# SQL Server : check column has member for other column but not others

Tags: sql, sql-server

The topic/header is not that intuitive, I just have to make an example

Let's assume we have a table called `ARTICLE` like this:

```
ARTICLE (idArticle, IdConference, IdMagazine, DateSent, Title, Sector);
```

Question: insert a constraint such that `idArticle` has only an `IdConference` or only an `IdMagazine` - but never both.

Straight away I knew it will be something like:

```
Alter table Article
add constraint checkidArt check( )
```

but I'm at a loss how to specify that column `IdArticle` should have only an `IdConference` or only an `IdMagazine` value.

Comment: mysql or (MS)SQL-Server?

Comment: Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's SQL Server, since MySQL does not have check constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE Article
ADD CONSTRAINT checkidArt CHECK (IdConference IS NULL OR IdMagazine IS NULL)
```

Comment: ..soo simple, of course after one has seen the solution..aha

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MySQL` then it won't be possible to add a constraint as MySQL does not support `CHECK` constraint. [Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) the documentation:

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

So, your *only* option would be to use a `TRIGGER` with `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` and `MESSAGE_TEXT` to flag the error.

Comment: I'm using sqlserver..microsoft sql server..sorry

Comment: In which case @Nenad's answer will help you.